# should i use LEFT JOIN all the time when obtaining the data from more than two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Here below is the example of MySQL

```
SELECT A.hospital_id, A.name, A.distance, B.name, A.near_gate 
FROM hospital A, station B 
WHERE A.campus='".$campus."' 
      AND A.category='".$category."' 
      AND A.station = B.id
```

this example does works well though, but is it okay to use this example
right away, or should i add a word `LEFT JOIN`?

Thanks in advance ~ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is equivalent to following:

```
SELECT A.hospital_id, A.name, A.distance, B.name, A.near_gate 
FROM hospital A
JOIN station B ON A.station = B.id
WHERE A.campus='".$campus."' AND A.category='".$category."'
```

It's an inner `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`

*Update*

Actually, `FROM table1, table2` should result in `CROSS JOIN`.
However database engines are smart enought to figure out which condition from `WHERE` part should be used to determine `JOIN` condition and change it into `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: oh then when i don't write any word, it works like INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

As you are showing the example query and you say its working fine. For it you should use the `JOIN` not a `LEFT JOIN`. below is the query:

```
SELECT A.hospital_id, A.name, A.distance, B.name, A.near_gate 
       FROM hospital A JOIN station B ON A.station = B.id 
            WHERE A.campus='".$campus."' AND A.category='".$category."'";
```